# Sticky arrow keys on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, keyboard

I have been using Ubuntu 22.04 for 2+ years on my laptop, I have to reinstall it near a month ago and since then I observed that clicking on the arrow button doesn't always lead to some response from the system -- sometimes cursor is moved right or left, sometimes it stays frozen.

I have not noticed a pattern behind it. I haven't found yet what is the root cause of this behaviour.

I hope I will be able to find help for this issue here.

Thanks!